# Formal definition of CBIP algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I am working on online coloring algorithms and I felt on the implementation using the CBIP (Common boundary Intersection projection) method.
However, there is not much documentation online about it. The best I could find is [this lecture note](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~bor/2421f19/lectures/W4.pdf). It assumes it but does not talk about the algorithm itself.

So my question is "What is the formal or informal definition of the CBIP algorithm in the k-coloring optimization problem"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Common Boundary Intersection Projection algorithm can be found in:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0926580516301984